# How to use tree reorder in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, tree

I would like to generate new left / right values to sort my categories by 'name' ASC.

I tried:

```
$this->Category->reorder(array('id' => null, 'field' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'verify' => true));
```

So, I have few categories added in database (don't care about parent / child at the moment).

generateTreeList gave me this output (order by lft):

- Alaska
- Kanada
- Zimbabwe
- Polska
- Francja

But I want to get alphabetical order:

- Alaska
- Francja
- Kanada
- Polska
- Zimbabwe

So I would like to use reorder() to change lft values. It returns true but do nothing with lft / rght values.

I don't want to use find() in this case to order it - I need it for list in from.

Comment: `But it doesn't work.` In what way does it not work? an error message is given? What exactly are you expecting and what exactly happens (`generateTreeList` may be useful for providing debug information). Note that you don't need to pass any arguments to `reorder` - in the question you've specified all-defaults.

Comment: It works... it return true. But I did not note any changes in lft / rght values in my Categories table. I expected alphabetical sorted categories in generateTreeList output. But it doesn't change.

Comment: If you don't provide any further information it's not possible to help you.

Comment: start by editing the question to include all relevant information - don't use comments...

Comment: Please add/indicate the lft/rght field values for each row.

Comment: I think I have answer... it's stupid... I didn't enable parent_id to have null value. Now it works!

Comment: That's an interesting cause - please add the answer _as an answer_ and accept it otherwise SO will treat this question as unanswered.

Comment: Ok, but not today :) I have to wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ANSWER WHY IT DOES NOT WORK:**

I didn't check parent_id to have **null** value. There was '0' instead NULL. 
Now it works and my tree is reodreded by using reorder().